# Error on bulk request (Error 500) when performing DELETE/INSERT queries through the Workbench

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I am trying to run a DELETE/INSERT query through the GraphDB SPARQL Workbench and only get Error 500, Error on bulk request.

The query:

```
DELETE {
<http://example.com/old> ?p ?o.
?s ?pp <http://example.com/old>.
}
INSERT {
<http://example.com/new> ?p ?o.
?s ?pp <http://example.com/new>.
}
WHERE{
<http://example.com/old> ?p ?o.
?s ?pp <http://example.com/old>.
}
```

GraphDB EE is running on a Docker container and I have not gotten this error before until today, after restarting the machine. What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: the `WHERE` clause does a cartesian product as there are two triple patterns with no shared variables - don't mix this up with a `UNION` which should be preferred here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. It seemed like the ElasticSearch service was down and had to be restarted, hence the Error 500 when performing any delete or insert queries to the repository